# AngularJS ng-repeat not updating after database insert

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS. I have been stuck on this all night. I have a form and I want the table to add the new row once I click SUBMIT. The form works fine and adds the document to mongodb but I can not see the update on the table with the binding until I refresh the page.

What am I missing? I see examples on using PUSH but that only seems to work on one dimensional arrays.

**ANGULARJS**

```
app.factory('SiteFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/sites/:id',{ id:'@_id' });
});

app.controller('SiteListController', function($scope, $location, SiteFactory) {

  // GET LIST OF SITES
  var sites = SiteFactory.query();
  $scope.sites = sites;

  $scope.createSite = function () {

    // validate data passed
    var domain = $scope.domain.trim();
    if (!domain.length) {
        return;
    }
    // POST to API
    var newSite = new SiteFactory();
    newSite.domain         = domain;
    newSite.created        = new Date();
    newSite.$save();

    console.log($scope.sites);
    $scope.sites = SiteFactory.query();
    console.log($scope.sites);
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="SiteListController">
<input type="text" ng-model="domain">
<button type="button" ng-click="createSite()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
...
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="site in sites | orderBy:'domain'">
<td>{{site.domain}}</td>
<td>{{site.created}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
...
```

**CONSOLE.LOG**

**BEFORE:**

```
[f, f, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]
0: f
1: f
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]

EXAMPLE:
    0: f 
    _id: "53d21d42f9406200001eddc6" 
    created: "2014-07-25T09:02:58.215Z" 
    domain: "originaldata1"
    1: f 
    _id: "53d21d42f9406200001eddc7" 
    created: "2014-07-25T09:02:58.215Z" 
    domain: "originaldata2"
```

**AFTER:**

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
0: f
1: f
2: f
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]

EXAMPLE:
    0: f 
    _id: "53d21d42f9406200001eddc6" 
    created: "2014-07-25T09:02:58.215Z" 
    domain: "originaldata1"
    1: f 
    _id: "53d21d42f9406200001eddc7" 
    created: "2014-07-25T09:02:58.215Z" 
    domain: "originaldata2"
    2: f 
    _id: "53d21d42f9406200001eddc8" 
    created: "2014-07-25T09:12:58.215Z" 
    domain: "newdata2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     $scope.createSite = function () {

        // validate data passed
        var domain = $scope.domain.trim();
        if (!domain.length) {
            return;
        }
        // POST to API
        var newSite = new SiteFactory();
        newSite.domain         = domain;
        newSite.created        = new Date();
        newSite.$save();
//please add new site to arrays of sites
        $scope.sites.push(newSite);

      };
```

Comment: I had tried that. It doesn't work. I can see the new item in the table after a refresh of the page. The DOM doesn't update.

Comment: Ca you please add this line to $scope.createSite console.log($scope.sites) and let me know what you get

Comment: i added console.log($scope.sites) output to the original question above.

Comment: @KyleAnderson your mongodb returning object instead of array so you can replace 'push' line with that $scope.sites = SiteFactory.query(); or configure mongodb to return array instead of object

Comment: $scope.sites = SiteFactory.query(); did not work. I think Angular Resource is what is making it an object. The API is returning a JSON array.

Comment: newSite.$save({}, fucntion(){$scope.sites = SiteFactory.query()});

Comment: Nope. It runs the function. Saves the item. Still needs page refresh to see it in the table. I'm stumped. O_o

Comment: I added a 6 second setTimeout before running .query. Still doesn't update. Hmmm...

Comment: @KyleAnderson can you check in delveper tools if $resource sending request to mongodb after save or just using cached data ?

Comment: i updated the console log above. I ran console.log($scope.sites); before and after .query. It looks like the new data is in there but its ordered differently (so failing?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58031/discussion-between-sylwester-and-kyle-anderson).

Comment: i come to the conclusion there was some conflicting JS I could not find. Your answer above should work.